# Set Default Security Key Settings (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-hello, yubikey, windows-11-preview

As of the latest Windows Insider Build (Dev Channel), 23541.1000 ni_prerelease, the following appears when Windows is prompted for security key input:

[image]

Whereas before this update, it was only `Security key`, and would automatically start the prompt for "touch the key." I do not have a phone connected to the machine, nor will I ever, and ideally I want to completely disable the `iPhone, iPad, or Android device` option.

I cannot find any settings in `Sign-in options` that would indicate it's possible to set a default, or disable the option at all, so I have a feeling registry messing is in order, but have no idea where that would be.

Comment: _(This doesn't address your question)_ Are you familiar with PassKeys? It doesn't require connecting a mobile device to the PC, it allows using a mobile device as the hardware security key since devices supporting PassKey are as secure as using a YubiKey or similar. A few articles: Tom's Guide: [What are passkeys? Everything you need to know about the death of passwords](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/what-are-passkeys) | Google: [Passwordless login with passkeys](https://developers.google.com/identity/passkeys) | Apple: [About the security of passkeys](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102195)

Comment: I cannot find anything about this particular change with regards to Passkey and WIndows Hello in reference to 23H2.  So I can only assume it's always been possible and the change is simple connected to a system change.  If you create a new user, does the same behavior exhbit itself, I truely expect this issue to be unique to your ssytem not an underline isssue with 23541.1000 (which by the way is NOT the current build) 23545.1000 is the current build.

Comment: I can only find the overall change that allows Passkeys to authenticate Windows Hello.  Which means that yours sytem (perhaps erronously) picked up your phone. We will need more debugging information to come up with a solution to the problem you describe. Make sure your phone isn't connected to your Microsoft account as outlined [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sign-in-to-your-microsoft-account-with-windows-hello-or-a-security-key-800a8c01-6b61-49f5-0660-c2159bea4d84)

Comment: Being that this is prerelease software, have you checked MS support forums, the Feedback app, and release notes?

Comment: This has now made it into the release version of Windows 11, and I too want to at least have the default set to 'Security Key', if not disable the phone options entirely. I can find no documentation on this from Microsoft.

Comment: oh man.  Between this and a password manager browser extension - I now need at least 4 mouse clicks before I can just tap my dang key.  passkey life is remarkably more complex.

Comment: [I finally got fed up enough to open a Microsoft Answers question about it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_11-security/disable-iphone-ipad-or-android-device-option-for/3c83b399-8dfd-4d5a-9945-0a14acd58e10). Will form that into an answer should I get any helpful information.

Comment: And now that Answers has become a fruitless endeavor, I've opened up a [Feedback hub post about it](https://aka.ms/AAngcx4). Microsoft is running me in goddamn circles with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Bluetooth smartphone FIDO CTAP option was broadly released in [Windows 11 22H2 Moment 4 (September 2023)](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-11-moment-4-update-released-here-are-the-many-new-features/).

I couldn't find any registry keys or files that `CredentialUIBroker.exe` or any of its loaded libraries would use to disable this new behavior.

Instead, I was able to write a background program that automatically selects the Security Key option and hits Next for you whenever this dialog box appears. All you have to do during authentication is type your security key PIN (if required) and touch the key, just like in previous Windows versions.

[**AuthenticatorChooser** on GitHub](https://github.com/Aldaviva/AuthenticatorChooser)

This .NET program uses Microsoft UI Automation to inspect and manipulate the dialog box.

I hope it's helpful for people.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were down-voted. This is a much better temporary solution than "turn off Bluetooth system-wide." Although I'd love a fix from MS themselves, we may see heat-death before then.

Answer (score 1):

Within [Disable "iPhone, iPad, or Android device" option for Passkey Sign-in](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-iphone-ipad-or-android-device-option-for/3c83b399-8dfd-4d5a-9945-0a14acd58e10?page=3), I've found a workaround posted by iEzJay; it does work for me as well, and the annoying dialog is gone, as is the random delay introduced by it:

- Open Device Manager → Disable Bluetooth adapter

Comment: Wow, it's worth noting that "disabling" Bluetooth via the Windows Settings app isn't enough, you really do need to disable the device via device manager.  Great find @pQd!

Comment: As I've noted on that answer, this is not a viable solution, as I use bluetooth for audio, and completely disabling a core feature of windows is not a solution, but a workaround, and a janky one at that.

Comment: @David - i'm not claiming this to be variable solution. it's the best and only dirty workaround that i'm aware of.

Comment: _(Please use correct markdown, such as for weblinks - please see the formatting bar or the `?` button to the far right on the formatting bar)_. Disabling a core networking and communication feature of an OS is a very poor solution to an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to disable Bluetooth, I have a way to very quickly select the "Security key". Just press: <kbd>TAB</kbd> -> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> -> <kbd>TAB</kbd> -> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This doesn't fix the problem, but makes this Windows Security prompt at least bearable.

Comment: This could be expanded upon further by automating with a hotkey through [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com)

Comment: I just assigned one of the macro keys on my keyboard to `TAB` `SPACE` `TAB` `SPACE` (no need to install extra software if you're already have macro keys)